# setting paths using getStaticPaths?

Tags: next.js

So suppose I have these 3 paths for routing in the form of an array:

```
const routes = ["route1", "route2", "route3"];
```

I would be doing this to set the paths:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const routes = ["route1", "route2", "route3"];

  const paths = routes.map((route) => ({ params: { id: route } }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false, 
  };
}
```

What I could not understand what is happening inside the map function. Kindly someone explain please?

Answer (score 0):

map() is a standard Javascript function.

This converts the array ["route1", "route2", "route3"] to an array of objects:

[{params: {'id': 'route1'}}, {params: {'id': 'route2'}}, params: {{'id': 'route3'}}]

This is the standard formatting documented by NextJS [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)